# R/Igraph Display edge weights in an edge list?

Tags: r, igraph

Is there any way to display edge weights when viewing the graph object as an edge list?

I want to do something in the spirit of:

```
get.edgelist(graph, attr='weight')
```

so as to view the edge pairings with the weights listed alongside the nodes, but that seems not to be allowed.  Only way I know how to view the weights is to view the network data as an adjacency matrix. Hoping that's not the only way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the example in the help page for function `get.edgelist` in pkg:igraph:

```
> cbind( get.edgelist(g) , round( E(g)$weight, 3 ))
      [,1] [,2] [,3]   
 [1,] "a"  "b"  "0.342"
 [2,] "b"  "d"  "0.181"
 [3,] "b"  "e"  "0.403"
 [4,] "b"  "f"  "0.841"
 [5,] "d"  "f"  "0.997"
 [6,] "e"  "g"  "0.029"
 [7,] "a"  "h"  "0.17" 
 [8,] "b"  "j"  "0.69" 
 [9,] "g"  "j"  "0.422"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `get.data.frame()` from the `igraph` package

```
# create a random graph with weighted edges      
g <- erdos.renyi.game(5, 5/10, directed = TRUE)
E(g)$weight <- runif(length(E(g)), 1, 5)

# pull nodes and edge weights
get.data.frame(g)

   from to   weight
1     1  5 4.716679
2     2  1 4.119414
3     1  2 4.535791
4     2  5 2.486553
5     3  2 4.932118
6     5  2 3.353693
7     1  3 3.003062
8     2  3 3.350118
9     1  4 2.929069
10    2  4 4.929474
11    5  4 4.333134
```